# PHP - Transorm text with commas to an array variables and make in IF statement after

Tags: php, arrays

Guys i have maybe a very simple question but i don't know how to make it.

How can i transform a following text into an array of variables.

```
$NotParsedString = "123456,654987,789456,321465";

foreach($results['data'] as $item){

    $PostID = $item['id'];
    if($PostID != $AnyIDfromNotParsedString){
        echo 'Show this thing';
    }
}
```

Simply i want to remove all the commas from `$NotParsedString` and make them as alone IDs which i can compare to `$PostID` and if `$PostID` is not same as any of theese IDs to `echo 'Show this thing';`

I hope you get the whole idea of what i am trying to do.

I want something like `if $PostID is not equal to 123456` or `if $PostID is not equal to 654987` and so on for the ones left till the end.

Can you help me out guys?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: 1. http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php 2. http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php

Comment: What would be your expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use [`in_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) combined with [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) like this:

```
if(!in_array($PostID, explode(",", $NotParsedString))){
```

Comment: I've marked you answer as a resolving answer, but you have an incorect code. `if(!in_array($PostID, explode(",", $NotParsedString)){` must be `if(!in_array($PostID, explode(",", $NotParsedString))){` Thanks :)

Comment: @TonyStark Ah yeah forgot one bracket

Answer (score 1):

Just use the explode() function.

```
$NotParsedString = "123456,654987,789456,321465";
$ids = explode(',', $NotParsedString);
```

$ids will be as following.

```
Array
(
    [0] => 123456
    [1] => 654987
    [2] => 789456
    [3] => 321465
)
```

Comment: but this will only remove the comma and it will not make an array from the left ids ?